# How can I get the :focus outline around an image link to not cut it off?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the look of the focus outline for when someone is tabbing through the website.  The CSS I'm using is below:

```
:focus { outline: solid 6px orange; outline-offset: 3px }
```

The image link is generated using the below html:

```
<A href="http://www.google.com"><IMG src="http://us.usablenet.net/mt/a/hyatt.com/l1398691219000/icons/info.png"></A>
```

However for a link that has an image, this style is cutting through the image instead of around it.
I can't post images, but here is the imgur link to the related screenshots taken from when I was trying to debug the issue on the Tryit Editor from w3schools

[image]

[image]

[image]

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k6vsckue/

Comment: I see it making a box around the image (Don't see it cutting into the img)? http://jsfiddle.net/qp7xg5q4/  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 38.0.2125.122 - Tested on Firefox and it works.  So probably a chromium error

Comment: Hmm, yeah can't use chrome here but that is interesting..  Are you applying other CSS to the `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` elements are displayed `inline` by default. The `height` property of inline elements cannot be change and so the image is overflowing out of the container. The outline on the `a` element then appears to 'cut' through it.

You can, however, change the display type to `inline-block` so the a's height will change to fit its image and achieve the effect you want.

CSS

```
A { display:inline-block; }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ho7rf46/

Comment: Actually, do you know why in the last picture, the outline is around the entire image?